# Dispatched an action once and it gets rendered twice instead of it being rendered once

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I'm fairly new to react and i'm making a simple expense application. The problem i'm facing is that i dispatch an action from my root component and when i console.log the store expense, i get one item in the store. But when i try to get the store from my sub component to render the expenses already dispatched to the store, i get two items. I tried to debug the issue but i don't understand the reason for such behaviour and also on subsequent dispatched actions, all the items are showing twice.
This is the code of the dispatch

```
import configureStore from "./store/configureStore";
import { addExpense } from "./actions/expenses";
import getVisibleExpenses from "./selectors/expense";

function App() {
  const store = configureStore;

  store.dispatch(
    addExpense({
      description: "water bill",
      createdAt: 5000,
      amount: 300,
    })
  );
  store.dispatch(
    addExpense({ description: "food bill", amount: 2000, createdAt: 1000 })
  );
  const state = store.getState();
  const visibleExpense = getVisibleExpenses(state.expenses, state.filters);
  console.log(visibleExpense);
```

And this is the expense.js file where the expense is rendered twice for one

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ExpenseListItem from "./ExpenseListItem";
import getVisibleExpenses from "../selectors/expense";


function ExpenseList({ expenses }) {
  console.log(expenses);
   
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Expense List</h1>
      {expenses.map((expense) => [
        <ExpenseListItem
          key={expense.id}
        {...expense}
        />,
      ])}
    </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    expenses: getVisibleExpenses(state.expenses, state.filters)
   
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpenseList);
```

Incase you need any other info to answer the question, let me know in the comments. Thanks

Comment: you are calling `store.dispatch` twice, one for water bill and another for food bill thats the reason you can see both. comment anyone and check

Comment: @Amruth L S. Actually thats, not the case. the problem is that in my browser, each of the expenses is rendered twice but i dispatch them ones

Answer (score 2):

You're dispatching actions in the middle of rendering. That is a "side effect", and you should never cause side effects while rendering React components.

What you're seeing here is that React double-renders components in development when inside of a `<StrictMode>` tag, *specifically* to help you catch errors like this because the results will be noticeable.

You should move all that Redux store interaction outside of this component.

Comment: actually all of my redux store interactions are outside the component. They are just in the js file. Can you elaborate more on your explanation please i have still been unable to debug the issue

Comment: i tried making some adjustments to how i render the expenses, but all to no avail. I need the store to render the expenses so i don't understand how i'm going to render the expenses if i take the store out of the component as a whole( i.e the js file)

Comment: The store _does not go in a component_. The store gets created _outside_ of the component tree,  you render a `<Provider store={store}>` around your top-level `<App>` component, and then you use the React-Redux `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks in your component to read state and dispatch actions (but still not dispatching in the middle of rendering). Please see the Redux docs tutorials for instructions on how to do this correctly: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index , https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start .